# Create a Sprite struct to hold an SDL surface and texture

Tags: rust, sdl, sdl-2

New to [rust](/questions/tagged/rust), I'm trying my hand at a simple [sdl](/questions/tagged/sdl) project.

I want to create a `Sprite` struct to hold the surface & texture to display a simple image.

My attempt so far:

```rust
pub struct Sprite<'a> {
    //surface : sdl2::surface::Surface<'a>,
    texture : sdl2::render::Texture<'a>,
}

impl Sprite<'_> {
    pub fn new<'a, P: AsRef<std::path::Path>>(
        canvas: &mut sdl2::render::WindowCanvas,
        path: P
        ) -> Result<Sprite<'a>, String>
    {
        let surface = sdl2::surface::Surface::load_bmp(path)?;
        let texture_creator = canvas.texture_creator();
        let texture = texture_creator.create_texture_from_surface(&surface).unwrap();

        Ok(Sprite {
            //surface,
            texture,
        })
    }
}
```

Sadly, `texture_creator` gets borrowed by the `create_texture_from_surface` call which gives me:

> **error[E0515]**: cannot return value referencing local variable `texture_creator`

I don't know how to work around this issue and need help to understand it

Comment: Your `texture` references `surface`. So if you return both `surface` and `texture`, `surface` moves in memory while `texture` references the old address, creating a dangling reference. Rust does not allow this, and therefore you can't do this. For more info, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link @Finomnis. I tried removing the `surface` attribute from the struct (I don't really need it), but the error is still the same.
The only way I found to make it work was to create the texture each time I need to display it, which seems needlessly wasteful

Comment: The error is still the same because it still references a local variable. This isn't a compiler error in other languages like C/C++, but still undefined behavior. Let me reproduce your problem and see if I can come up with better advice.

Comment: @Finomnis I'm coming up with something, I need to keep the reference to the texture_creator in a place that owns the sprite so its lifetime is bigger than the sprite.

Comment: @Finomnis can you post your initial comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If that's a valid answer for you, let me mark it as a duplicate.